# Java Code to fetch Session Store attribute values

Tags: java, siteminder

I am writing an Assertion Generator Plugin in Java to fetch a user details from Session Store and modify the values in Assertion(SAML 2.0) accordingly.

I am able to identify the method([Link](https://supportcontent.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP2-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/javadoc-sm/netegrity/siteminder/javaagent/AgentAPI.html#getSessionVariables%28java.lang.String,%20netegrity.siteminder.javaagent.ResourceContextDef,%20netegrity.siteminder.javaagent.AttributeList,%20netegrity.siteminder.javaagent.AttributeList%29)) using which I can pull the user values from Session Store (agentAPIObject.getSessionVariables()) based on SessionID, but, I am having trouble writing a code to fetch specific parameters from the session store. (speficially around setting values for Attribute method and making it as an array)

Can someone post a sample code if you have ever seen/written around it, so that I can fetch user attributes from Session Store.

I am having trouble understanding Java docs around it.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What's your code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API mentions this:

> ***responseAttributeList*** - On successful return from this method (YES is
>   returned), this output parameter contains the retrieved variable names
>   and their values. If the method returns UNRESOLVED, this parameter
>   includes variables that could not be retrieved.

You'll need to create two [AttributeList](https://supportcontent.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP2-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/javadoc-sm/netegrity/siteminder/javaagent/AttributeList.html) Objects.  If the response of `getSessionVariables(...)` is `YES`, then the variable `responseAttributeList` will contain the session variables.  Since Java uses references, that same variable `responseAttributeList` will be updated.  You can then use getAttributeAt(...) to access the [Attribute](https://supportcontent.ca.com/cadocs/0/CA%20SiteMinder%20r12%20SP2-ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/javadoc-sm/netegrity/siteminder/javaagent/Attribute.html) Objects.

```
String sessionID = "sampleID";
ResourceContextDef rcd = //whatever it needs to be equal to
AttributeList requestAttributeList = new AttributeList();
AttributeList responseAttributeList = new AttributeList();

if(getSessionVariables(sessionId, rcd, requestAttributeList, responseAttributeList) == YES){
    Attribute att = responseAttributeList.getAttributeAt(0);//or whatever index. 
}
```

Remember to carefully read the API.

**NOTE**:  This is just pseudo code.  I have not tested this.  However, this should be plenty enough to get you going where you need to.

Comment: I have two more queries. 1. The method getSessionVariables is of type "public int" but in return section it mentions "Yes/No/Unresolved/etc..."?                              2. In Attribute class how do I set values of flags "public int flags"? I am using this method... requestAttributeList.addAttribute(int id, int ttl, int flags, java.lang.String oid, byte[] value) and flags is of integer type but few Strings are mentioned as constant values for it like "SM_AGENTAPI_REQATTR_FLAGS_DELETE
/SM_AGENTAPI_REQATTR_FLAGS_NONE/etc." ?

Comment: @user3556979 `YES`, `NO`, etc are all defined in that class as `final int`.  It's near the top of the API.  The second question is a completely different question on it's own, but read the API carefully.  It seems to be mentioning it.  Don't be scared to try code yourself...sometimes API are meant for you to experiment with.  |=^]